# How to programmatically update datagrid columns headerText

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, ria

I have a Datagrid that is being populated by an ArrayCollection (rows) of Arrays (columns).  I need to update the headerText of each column based on a List that will correspond with the total number of items within each array in the arraycollection.

What is the best way of doing this?

I know that I can set a listener in the List and update the headerText using (matrixDatagrid.columns[i] as DataGridColumn).headerText but I am looking for a cleaner solution.

Is there a way to do this using an itemRenderer in the Datagrid?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe has a write up on [Passing values to headerrenderer](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Passing_values_to_headerrenderer-10624.html) that has an example on how to dynamically pass data to your HeaderRenderer. Hopefully it helps. :)

Comment: Your answer was not really what I was looking for but thanks for trying to help. :)

Comment: @Rie Mino, No worries. It would help me get an idea of what you're looking for if you posted a code snippit of what your data and DataGrid look like. :)